# Can dermatomal problems possibly indicate other medical conditions?

Tags: neurology, spine, nerves, neuropathy, spinal-cord-compression

I have been reading up about [dermatomes](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/what-are-dermatomes) and it got me wondering if dermatomal issues can indicate potential problems further into the body than the dermis?

For a couple of examples, can say one of T1 to T6 affect anything around the heart or lungs? I can understand that S2 and S3 can affect sexual responses within the genitalia of a man or woman, but can one of say, T11 to S2 affect any of the reproductive organs?

Comment: Your link says S3 affects the genitals. Did you mean to say T11 to S2?

Comment: @CareyGregory - hmmm yes. I believe you are right in what I meant to say 